# How to access to external files from Phar archives?

Tags: php, phar

I need to place config file out of phar of my web application. I need to mount it. In my stub file I tried:

```
<?php
try {
    Phar::mount('sites/site.php', __DIR__.'/../sites/site.php');
} catch (PharException $e) {
    print_r($e);
};
Phar::mapPhar();
include '../app.phar';
```

however, I got " `Mounting of sites/site.php to D:\(...)\public/../sites/site.php failed`" error message. I tried various file path styles without any success. What is wrong with it?

I use box2 to ubild phar files. It take a long time to build the phar file. Is there any way to make it faster?

The error message is also vague. Any way to get better message?

Comment: have you tried changing slashes `/` with anti slashes `\ ` ? Since you are on windows ? And even further : have you considered using [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant to be sure that you are OS independent ?

Comment: @b.enoit.be Windows accepts both ‍‍`/‍` and `\\` as directory separator.

Comment: On Linux this doesn't work as well. The problem is `__DIR__` which translates to `phar:///var/www/....`. If I use just a full path (`/var/www/...`), then the mounting works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use an internal phar uri as a mounting point like:

```
 Phar::mount('phar://sites/site.php', __DIR__.'/../sites/site.php');
```

Also I don't know if the problem could be due the `sites` subdir, did you try:

```
 Phar::mount('site.php', __DIR__.'/../sites/site.php');
```

Comment: Yes, It did not helped.

Comment: The same error? Could you paste the complete PHP error log here?